# Geting php error for array_merge and array_unique

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below are the arrays and the code I am trying to unique/merge

```
$data['default_new'] = array_unique(array_merge($data['default'], $data['related']))



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [keywords_id] => 8
            [keyword] => Curling
            [parent_id] => 5
            [count] => 0
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [keywords_id] => 8
            [keyword] => Curling
            [parent_id] => 5
            [count] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [keywords_id] => 10
            [keyword] => Catchers
            [parent_id] => 6
            [count] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [keywords_id] => 16
            [keyword] => CES 2013
            [parent_id] => 3
            [count] => 0
        )

)
```

It gives me an array to string  error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: models/content_model.php

Line Number: 29
```

I had this problem with unique and merge before and never fixed it!

I am using codeigniter

here is more info regarding the function I am using array_unique/merge in:

```
    public function results($data, $searched)
    {
        $page['searched'] = $searched;
        $page['is_active'] = $this->logic_model->is_active();
        $data2 = array();
        $data2['default_new'] = array_unique(array_merge($data['default'], 
$data['related']));
}
```

line 29 is the `$data2['default_new'] = array_u`

the `$data` parameter contains, `default` and `regular` which can be seen above.

vardump of data:

```
array(3) {
  ["active"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["keyword"]=>
    string(6) "Sports"
  }
  ["related"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["keywords_id"]=>
      string(1) "8"
      ["keyword"]=>
      string(7) "Curling"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
  ["default"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["keywords_id"]=>
      string(1) "8"
      ["keyword"]=>
      string(7) "Curling"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["keywords_id"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["keyword"]=>
      string(8) "Catchers"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      ["keywords_id"]=>
      string(2) "16"
      ["keyword"]=>
      string(8) "CES 2013"
      ["parent_id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @adamdunson I added more info above.

Comment: paste a `var_dump($data)` from within your `results()` function

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 added vardump for you

Comment: is that a vardump from within the `results()` function?

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 yes its straight from results()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Notes section here: http://us.php.net/array_unique#refsect1-function.array-unique-notes

You're going to need to come up with your own algorithm for creating a unique multidimensional array. Some of the comments at my link above suggest various methods for accomplishing this, e.g., [this one](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#91134):

```
<?php
$values = array();

foreach($data as $d) {
    $values[md5(serialize($d))] = $d;
}

sort($values);
?>
```

Related questions on SO: [strange behavior of php array_unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403729/strange-behavior-of-php-array-unique) and [How do I use array_unique on an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561248/php-array-unique)

Answer (score 1):

The error is not coming from the `array_unique` or `array_merge` function calls.

The problem is that you defined `$data` as a `string` previously.

This should fix it:

```
$data = array();
$data['default_new'] = array_unique(array_merge($data['default'], $data['related']))
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work . I added more info above.  Defining `$data = array();` erased `default` and `related`.

Comment: based on the error from php, `$data['default']` and `$data['related']` do not exist because `$data` is a `string`

Comment: I obtained the array's above by using `print_r` so I know the values exist and in array format.  The error comes on the line with the unique and merge functions.  I received a different error when trying your fix.  Can I define $data as a string in different function?

Comment: the keys in your array from the print_r are numeric.. You are trying to access keys that are strings.. If you are getting a different error then your original question has been answered and you should ask another one.

And a function variable only exists in the function scope http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: The new error is `Undefined index: default` and `Undefined index: related` its not fixed :\

Comment: understood, but the original error is fixed.. now you are getting a new error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function appClasses()
{
    $data = config('custom.custom');

    // default data array
    $DefaultData = [
        'myLayout' => 'vertical',
        'myTheme' => 'theme-default',
        'myStyle' => 'light',
        'myRTLSupport' => true,
        'myRTLMode' => true,
        'hasCustomizer' => true,
        'showDropdownOnHover' => true,
        'displayCustomizer' => true,
        'contentLayout' => 'compact',
        'headerType' => 'fixed',
        'navbarType' => 'fixed',
        'menuFixed' => true,
        'menuCollapsed' => false,
        'footerFixed' => false,
        'customizerControls' => [
            'rtl', 'style', 'headerType', 'contentLayout', 'layoutCollapsed', 'showDropdownOnHover',
            'layoutNavbarOptions', 'themes',
        ],
        //   'defaultLanguage'=>'en',
    ];

    $data = array_unique(array_merge($DefaultData, $data));
}
```

Comment: It gives me an  error: $data= array_unique(array_merge($DefaultData,$data));

Comment: Do not post an answer because you have a similar problem -- that is not how Stack Overflow's Q&A works.  See the comprehensive list of techniques that you might use to remove duplicates at: [Filter/Remove rows where column value is found more than once in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604306/2943403)